# The syntax <T extends Class<T>> in Java

Tags: java, generics, syntax

I have couple of thoughts regarding the following:

```
public interface MaxStack<T extends Comparable <T>>
```

1-Why does the class that implements `MaxStack` should be written like this:

```
public class MaxStackclass<T extends Comparable <T>> implements MaxStack<T>
```

and not `public class MaxStackclass<T extends Comparable <T>> implements MaxStack<T extends Comparable <T>>`?

2- why do the private variables of this class, when I use generics, should be written only with `<T>` and not with `<T extnds Comparable<T>>`? For example,  `private List<T> stack= new ArrayList<T>();`

3-What is the difference between `<T extends Comparable<T>>` and `<T extends Comparable>`- if I need to compare bewteen elements in my class, both will be O.K, no?

Edit: I think that thee problem with 3 is that maybe it allows to insert of a list that was defined in the second way to have different elements which all extends from comparable and then when I want to compare them, it won't be possible, since we can't compare String to Integer, both extend from Comparable.

Comment: Just a nitpick on style: the name of your public class is not CamelCase, a convention that avoids misunderstandings. While it's not such an issue with nested classes, in this case it's a public class...

Comment: for best results use `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. In the declaration `maxStackclass<T extends Comparable <T>>` you have already expressed the bounds on `T`. So you do not need it again.
2. Reason same as above. No need to specify bounds on the same type parameter again.
3. `<T extends Comparable<T>>` means that `T` must implement the `Comparable` interface that can compare two `T` instances. While `<T extends Comparable>` means `T` implements `Comparable` such that it can compare two `Object`s in general. The former is more specific.

> if I need to compare bewteen elements in my class, both will be O.K,
>   no?

Well, technically you *can* achieve the same result using both. But for the declaration `<T extends Comparable>` it will involve unnecessary casts which you can avoid using the type safe `<T extends Comparable<T>>`

Answer (score 2):

1) the class has a type parameter `T` with a bound (`extends Comparable <T>`), this parameter is passed to the interface (which need the same bound here). When passing a type parameter, you must not repeat its bound - why you should do so?

2) like 1), the type parameter has its bound declared, no repeat neccessary.

To clarify:

The first type parameter occurence (here behind the interface or class name) is its declaration. Any following occurence is a usage. You even never would write a variables type declaration each time you use it, right?

Answer (score 2):

"3-What is the difference between `<T extends Comparable<T>>` and `<T extends Comparable>`- if I need to compare bewteen elements in my class, both will be O.K, no?"

No, both will not be okay. Suppose I have a class `Foo` which `implements Comparable<Bar>` but classes Foo and Bar have no relation to each other. Then `Foo` cannot compare to other objects of type `Foo`. `<T extends Comparable<T>>` will catch this as a problem. `<T extends Comparable>` will not.